# ElasticSearch/Kibana: The correct syntax to exclude a value?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm racking my brain trying to work out why this search doesn't work properly. I want to find all documents where `instance=ko14274` but exclude any that are `maxlevel=UNKNOWN`. I have tried the following:

```
instance:ko14274 AND NOT maxlevel:UNKNOWN
instance:ko14274 AND -maxlevel:UNKNOWN
instance:ko14274 AND maxlevel:(-UNKNOWN)
instance:ko14274 AND -(maxlevel:UNKNOWN)
```

It still returns some results that should not be in the result set, but not all. is there a margin of error or estimation?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You must enable "Turn on query features" in the SYNTAX OPTIONS.